# plot colors by color values in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

```
raw_data = {'Enum': ['E330','E322','E124','E500'],'Count': [234, 122, 765, 433],
'Colors':['red','blue','green','yellow']}

additives_count = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
```

I want to plot a bar graph and I used the code below.

```
ax = additives_count.plot(kind='barh',colors=additives_count['Colors'])
```

The only issue is I am not able to make the respective colors appear with the Enum. I got my bar plot, but only 1 color. So for instance, my plot should have E330 plotted as red, E322 as blue, E124 as green and E500 as yellow. How can I achieve this?

Do note that this is just a very small subset of my data. I have a total of  30 rows to plot, but i believe you get the gist of what I am trying to achieve. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: thanks for the edit! As per my comment below, even after specifying the x and y, my bar plots only in 1 color. My versions as matplotlib (2.1.0), panda(0.20.3) and Py (3)

Comment: My versions are matplotlib(2.0.2) and pandas(0.22.0) and python 3. Try updating pandas version. @Zoozoo

Comment: Thanks! updated, and works now! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifying the `x` and `y` data in the plotting call seems to solve the problem:

```
ax = additives_count.plot(x="Enum",y="Count",kind='barh',color=additives_count['Colors'])
```

Note that `colors` is being depreciated, so it is recommended to use `color`. This will give:

[image]

Comment: thanks! I copied and paste exactly your code onto a new notebook, but strangely, my bar plot only output one color, which is red (the 1st one)

Comment: Noted on the colors syntax, much appreciated!

Comment: @Zoozoo try updating to the latest version of Pandas

Comment: pandas updated to 0.22, reimported my pandas in my jupyter notebook, but still doesnt work. :(

Comment: Ok it works now. I needed to completely shut down my notebook and relaunch. Thanks for the help and inputs. Cant believe how functionality differs from one version to another, need to remind myself to keep it updated and fresh! :)

Answer (score 4):

Specify which column is `x-axis` and which one is `y-axis`.

```
additives_count.plot(x='Enum', y='Count',kind='barh',color=additives_count['Colors'])
```

The output looks like this.
[image]